# Convergence of series with $a_{n} = \frac{(n+1)!}{\beta(\beta+1)(\beta+2)..(\beta+n)n^{a}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have $a_{n} = \frac{(n+1)!}{\beta(\beta+1)(\beta+2)..(\beta+n)n^{a}},\beta>0$. Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converge? I tried ratio test $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ and got $\frac{(n+1)^a(\beta+n+1)}{(n+2)}$, so i have $n^a$. Hence If $a>1$ then series converges. But according to wolfram if $a=2$ and $\beta = 1$,whole sum diverge. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I think your calculation $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is wrong.

Comment: @xpaul yes, thanks. Now my ratio equals to 1,so ratio test doesn't work. I tried Raabe's test, and got limit equals to infinity. So series converge for any a. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right) \\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{\beta(\beta+1)(\beta+2)..(\beta+n)n^{a}}\cdot \frac{\beta(\beta+1)(\beta+2)..(\beta+n+1)(n+1)^{a}}{(n+2)!}-1\right)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left( \frac{(\beta+n+1)(n+1)^{a}}{n^a(n+2)}-1\right)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\beta+n+1)(n+1)^{a}-n^a(n+2)}{n^{a-1}(n+2)}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{a+1}-n^{a+1}+\beta(n+1)^a-2n^a}{n^{a-1}(n+2)}\\
&=&a+\beta-1
\end{eqnarray}
and hence if $\rho>1$ or $a+\beta>2$, the series converges, and if $\rho<1$ or $a+\beta<2$, the series diverges. If $\rho=1$ or $a+\beta=2$, the test is inconclusive.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about $n^a$ term in denominator, shame on me